# How to create a local database in react js

Tags: reactjs, database, shopping-cart

what i'm trying to do is create a local database for user so when he adds an item to shopping cart it gets stored in there, and that database should be local and also unique for every user and basically it's based on they're `Api_key` so i was wondering what technologies should i use to create that database.

```
/// what i have tried to do
```

basically i tried storing the data's in `localStorage` of the browser but in this case it's no use.

Comment: Somethine like IndexDB? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to achieve here? There are things like [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb), but I don't think that's what you are after.

Comment: See basically it's gonna be an online supermarket with products, and each time the user clicks on adding the product, the shopping cart that is our data base in this example should be updated with the values, so be to as basic as possible it's gonna be a shopping cart that the user could see the item's he has added to it

Comment: You will most definitely need a backend for that. If you are not into that you can go serverless with Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like what you're looking for is a cookie. [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie)